# Getting Random number from an array

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have an array

```
a[1..5] : array of integer;
```

next I do some checks and set some of the values to 1.

```
DoesSomeDataCheck()
begin
  ... 
  if True
    a[Count] = 1;
  .....
end
```

now lets say that made the array values to :

```
a[1] = 1;
a[2] = 1;
a[3] = 0;
a[4] = 0;
a[5] = 1;
```

Now i need to get one of these randomly of all the integers that = 1.
No idea where to even start this..
but it should return a 1,2,5 in this case.
Hope this is clear if not let me know and ill try to explain it better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array to hold indices:

```
var 
  Indices: array [1..5] of Integer;
```

And a variable to hold the number of indices that have value 1 in original array:

```
var
  IndicesCount: Integer;
```

Initialise:

```
IndicesCount := 0;
for i := 1 to 5 do 
  if a[i] = 1 then
  begin
    Inc(IndicesCount);
    Indices[IndicesCount] := i;
  end;
```

Then you can sample randomly with

```
Assert(IndicesCount>0);
Sample := Indices[1 + Random(IndicesCount)];
```

---

Asides:

1. Zero-based indexing is generally to be preferred. It is more consistent with the RTL and extant libraries.
2. The array `a` looks awfully like it's elements should be of type `Boolean`.
3. It is conceivable that your code that builds `a` could instead directly build the `Indices` array in my answer. If you don't need `a` for any other purpose, that would be simpler.

Comment: I decided to not use zerobased, just cause the 1-5 is consistent with the data i am testing. The array could be boolean i just did it with integers , cause i thought it would be easier and yes A is just holding a 1 if the slot/area i am checking is empty.

Comment: David's code is guaranteed to give you one of your indices immediately, at the price of slightly more complicated code. If you know that the majority of your array values will be 1 you could just do a repeat i := Random(5)+1 until a[i]=1  Theoretically this could be undetermined, practically it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Take a dynamic array of integers to maintain indexes whose value is 1.

```
Var
   indexArray : Array of Integer;
   ..........
```

Change your DoesSomeDataCheck() as follows,

```
procedure DoesSomeDataCheck()
begin
  ... 
  if True
  begin
    a[Count] := 1;
    setLength(indexArray, Length(indexArray)+1);
    indexArray[Length(indexArray)-1] := Count;
  end;
  .....
end
```

Now you can make use of indexArray when ever you want. No need to check again.
    I hope this would be useful to you.

Comment: May I know where is the mistake in my code or how it is irrelevant to the question? So that I can improve in coding level...